# Redirect output half-way through a script, and restore later

Tags: zsh, io-redirection

I would like to re-direct stdout half-way through a script. How can I do this in Zsh?

```
# Do something
# ... 

# Redirect stdout to a file (e.g. foo.txt)
for x in *;
print $x;
done
# Re-direct stdout back to default

# Do something else
# ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `exec` builtin with a redirection but no command to redirect the shell's file descriptors. If you want to restore the original destination, you'll have to save it in another descriptor.

```
exec 3>&1 >foo.txt
for x in *; do
  print $x
done
exec >&3 3>&-
```

When the scope of the redirection is a portion of code, it is simpler to put the redirection around that piece of code.

```
for x in *; do
  print $x
done >foo.txt
```

If you want to apply a redirection to a sequence of instructions, put it inside braces.

```
{
  for x in *; do
    print $x
  done;
  echo 'one more line'
} >foo.txt
```

These constructs exist in all Bourne/POSIX-style shells, not just in zsh.

Comment: With a note that in the Bourne shell, redirecting a compound command causes a subshell, so it used to be desirable to use the `exec 3>&1...` there. Not anymore with modern shells.

Comment: The docs on IO redirections for Bash: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output of `for` easily enough with:

```
for foo in list; do
    somethingto $foo
done > /path/to/forloop_log.txt
```

This will only redirect the output of the `for` loop and not affect output before or after it.

You can accomplish the same thing for pretty much any command or set of commands by using a subshell:

```
dosomething
( dosomethingelse; doyetanotherthing; ) > /path/to/special.log
dostillanotherthing
```